# String interpolation trouble

Tags: swift, string

I don't understand why this gives me the result of (53,"˚") when it is on the app. I understand the number of 53 but why are the parentheses and the quotation marks showing up?

```
self.degreeLabel.text = "\(Int(self.locationDelegate.returnHeading()), "˚")"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Extracting the Int conversion from the string conversion should help identify the issue:

```
let degrees = Int(self.locationDelegate.returnHeading())
self.degreeLabel.text = "(\(degrees)˚)"
```

or if you do not want the parenthesis at all:

```
let degrees = Int(self.locationDelegate.returnHeading())
self.degreeLabel.text = "\(degrees)˚"
```

Comment: The \ was not missing. The question wasn't formatted correctly so you couldn't see the \ that was there.